# Existen Variables de entorno en asp net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Existen variables de entorno en asp net mvc o cual es su equivalente en esta version?

Comment: Checa [este tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) de Microsoft. Tiene todo lo relacionado a variables de entorno y a los diferentes perfiles que puedes configurar.

Comment: But that documentation  is only for net core .